# Compare dataframes and output the numbers of count matches

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count occurences of one dataframe in another dataframe and output the counts of matches.

```
df
   group1  group2
0  orange  orange
1   apple   apple
2  banana    pear
3  banana  banana
```

.

```
fruit_df
   fruits
0  orange
1  banana
```

So:

```
 groups = ["group1", "group2"]
 matrix = pd.DataFrame()
 for group in groups:
        out = fruit_df["fruits"].isin(df[group]).astype(int)
        matrix = pd.concat([matrix, out], axis = 1)
 matrix.columns = groups
 matrix = matrix.rename(index = fruit_df["fruits"])
```

Results in:

```
matrix
        group1  group2
orange       1       1
banana       1       1
```

What I would like is:

```
 matrix
        group1  group2
 orange      1       1
 banana      2       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one of the way you could try

```
temp_df = pd.melt(df, var_name='group', value_name='fruits')
temp_df['count'] = 1
df_count = temp_df.pivot_table(index=['fruits'], columns=['group'], values='count', aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index()
matrix = fruits_df.merge(df_count)
matrix.set_index('fruits')
print(matrix)
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per columns, select by values from `fruit_df['fruits']` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and if necessary replace missing values to `0` and convert to integers:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).loc[fruit_df['fruits']].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
        group1  group2
orange       1       1
banana       2       1
```

Comment: @pyd - Thank you. `df.groupby(fruit_df["fruit"])` cannot be used here, because different length of df and `fruit_df`