# Finding any of the elements exist in between two columns df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pattern-matching

I have df column contains number of integers. I want compare them and find any of the elements exist b/w two columns and tag as "yes" else "No" in new column and the number matches in another coulmn.

INPUT_df:

```
 A                                          B
[131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142,35]           [137,35]
[11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]    [137,33,16]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]        [20,19,33]
```

Desired OUTPUT_df:

```
 A                                          B             NOTE NO_MATCHED    
[131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]          [137,35] yes 137,35
[11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]    [137,33,16]  yes 33,16 
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]        [20,19,33]    No
```

I have tried looping over df but i would like to have a better way:

This is the way i tried:

```
save_p = []
for idx,row in INPUT_df.iterrows():
    for i in row.A:
        for j in row.B:
            if int(i) == int(j) :
                save_p.append((row.A,row.B,'yes','i','j'))
            else:
                save_p.append((row.A,row.B,,'No,'i','j))
```

Whether pd.isin might work?

Comment: The input dataframe you give, is different from output dataframe..

Comment: @Erfan corrected! thanks

Comment: It's still wrong, there's no 35, but we get the point. That's why my output is different from yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: `list comprehension & zip`:

We can use  `list comprehension` with `zip` here to compare the rows element wise:

```
df['NOTE'] = [any([x in a for x in b]) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]

df['NO_MATCH'] = [[x for x in b if x in a] for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

```
                                          A              B   NOTE   NO_MATCH
0        [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]      [137, 35]   True  [137, 35]
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137, 33, 16]   True   [33, 16]
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20, 19, 33]  False         []
```

---

#### Method 2: `intersection with set()`:

```
df['NOTE'] = [any(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]

df['NO_MATCH'] = [list(set(a) & set(b)) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

```
                                          A              B   NOTE   NO_MATCH
0        [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]      [137, 35]   True  [137, 35]
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137, 33, 16]   True   [16, 33]
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20, 19, 33]  False         []
```

**Intersection**:

[image]

---

**Note1**:
If you want `yes`, `no` instead of `True`, `False`, use `Series.map`:

```
df['NOTE'] = df['NOTE'].map({True: 'yes', False: 'no'})
```

```
                                          A              B NOTE   NO_MATCH
0        [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]      [137, 35]  yes  [137, 35]
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137, 33, 16]  yes   [16, 33]
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20, 19, 33]   no         []
```

---

**Note 2:** Plus, if you want `NO_MATCH` as `str` output:

```
df['NO_MATCH'] = df['NO_MATCH'].astype(str).str.replace('[\[\]]', '')
```

```
                                          A              B NOTE NO_MATCH
0        [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]      [137, 35]  yes  137, 35
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137, 33, 16]  yes   16, 33
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20, 19, 33]   no
```

---

**Note3**: If your list is string representation of a list, use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
print(df)
                                          A            B
0         [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142,35]     [137,35]
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137,33,16]
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20,19,33]
```

```
type(df['A'].iat[0])
# Out: str
```

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(literal_eval)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(literal_eval)

type(df['A'].iat[0])
# Out: list
```

Comment: @pyd - no, erfan solution is nice, maybe join should be used (but cannot upvote, because still not matching... unfortunately :()

Comment: any better solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745723/compare-dataframes-and-output-the-numbers-of-count-matches)

Comment: @pyd - you, solution should be better, added answer.

Comment: I think join lists

Comment: @Erfan  it doesnt work with a list as an object format! how would i deal with it?

Comment: See **note3** at the bottom @rajiv

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) 
to search duplicates by rows transforming both lists to a series using `pd.Series`.Then
You are selecting duplicates by [`callable`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) with [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). Finally you can `join` it and create a `NOTE` column checking if duplicates exits to use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['NOT MATCH']=df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(pd.Series(x.sum()).loc[lambda x: x.duplicated()].astype(str).dropna()),axis=1)
df['NOTE']=np.where(df['NOT MATCH'].eq('')|df['NOT MATCH'].isnull(),'No','Yes')
print(df)
```

---

```
                                          A              B NOT MATCH NOTE
0        [131, 138, 137, 140, 141, 142, 35]      [137, 35]    137,35  Yes
1  [11, 18, 59, 33, 61, 12, 13, 15, 60, 16]  [137, 35, 16]        16  Yes
2      [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   [20, 19, 33]             No
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to have filter functions (re-using @Erfan's method):

```
def match(cols):
    return [[x for x in b if x in a] for a, b in cols]

df['NO_MATCH'] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(match, axis = 1)
df['NOTE'] = df['NO_MATCH'].apply(any)
```

A possibly faster `match` function:

```
def match(cols):
    return np.array(cols[0])[np.in1d(*cols)].tolist()
```

you can also `assume_unique = True` to speed that up even more, if both lists only have unique values

```
def match(cols):
    return np.array(cols[0])[np.in1d(*cols, assume_unique = True)].tolist()
```